# Why does an imperfect cadence not include IV-I?

Tags: cadence

I am learning that an imperfect cadence only involves inverted chords with the V-I. Why is IV not included? Should an 'imperfect' plagal cadence be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition. The terms *perfect* and *imperfect* are defined specifically with regard to authentic (V-I) cadences. This is due to the exceptionally common nature of authentic cadences in a variety of different forms, each of which has a different musical effect.

Plagal cadences don't commonly occur in so large a variety of forms, so they are not given similar subcategories.

However, if we extend the "perfect" and "imperfect" definitions to include plagal cadences, then imperfect would actually be the norm. In a perfect authentic cadence, the final chord includes the tonic in the top voice. However, in a plagal cadence, scale degree 5 is very frequently in the top voice.

Plagal cadences tend to be in root position — that is, the lowest voice moves from 4 to 1 — but the top-most voice can have any of the pitches of the final tonic chord. Plagal cadences in which the IV and/or I chords are inverted are uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

There are different terms used - depending which side of the Atlantic you are. On the right, there are basically four cadences, whereas on the left, some of those are split again, regarding which inversion/voicing is used.

On the right, 'perfect' is one term. On the left, 'Authentic' is used instead, which then gets split into at least 'perfect authentic' and imperfect authentic'. This causes confusion (at least to me...).